# Get records from mySQL using PHP and send it to VB.net

Tags: php, mysql, database, vb.net, connection

I have a PHP script which accepts an argument and adds record in the mySQL database if its not available and if its already available it gives a message 'Record already found'.

How can i read this message from vb.net and do appropriate action such as

if data_is_in_db then msgbos("your record already found in the database")

if data_is_not_in_db then msgbox("your record has been added in the database")

Please help me for this, as i am a newbie.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to integrate a database connection inside your VB.NET application instead of trying to communicate with a PHP script. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

You can (amongst many other possibilities) use the http status message for that.

E.g send a [`201 Created`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2) when the record has been added and a [`409 Conflict`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) if the record is already there.

see also:
[void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )](http://docs.php.net/function.header)
[HttpWebResponse.StatusCode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx)